# Summarize data from indirectly related tables in PostgreSQL View in a preformant way

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, join, subquery

I've created the following query as a naïve solution for creating a view which gathers some data related to events with guest lists.

The idea is to gather attendance by show the registered number of parties and guests alongside the number of actual checked in guests and number of checkins (parties can check in multiple guests in one check in).

The following code gets the job done but I'd like a way to do it without unnecessary complexity

```
 SELECT
    g.id as guestlist,
    g.event,
    coalesce(p.parties,0) registered_parties,

    -- Does the job but uses subqueries, total number of guests registered
    coalesce(
        (SELECT
           sum(guest.guest_count)
         FROM guest
         WHERE guest.party IN  -- Especially smelly
               (SELECT party.id
                FROM party
                WHERE party.guestlist = g.id
               )
        ),
        0
    ) AS registered_guests,

    -- Sub query for getting how many guests attended
    coalesce(
      (SELECT
        sum(check_in.guest_count)
        FROM check_in
        WHERE check_in.guestlist = g.id
      ),
      0
    ) AS checked_in_guests,

    -- How many physical checkins were made (one can be a group of guests)
    coalesce(
      (SELECT
        count(check_in.id)
        FROM check_in
        WHERE check_in.guestlist = g.id
      ),
      0
    ) AS checkins
  FROM
    guestlist g
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT guestlist, count(*) parties
    FROM party
    GROUP BY guestlist
  ) p on p.guestlist = g.id
  ;
```

Running this query will result in something like this

```
guestlist   event   registered_parties  registered_guests   checked_in_guests   checkins
1           1       2                   5                   5                   3
2           1       0                   0                   0                   0
```

Below as HTML-table

```css
th, td{
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

*{
  color: #333;
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tr><th>guestlist</th><th>event</th><th>registered_parties</th><th>registered_guests</th><th>checked_in_guests</th><th>checkins</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a map over the relevant bits in the SQL-model.
[image: Domain model]

And data used to yield above results

Event-table
[image: event]

Guestlist-table
[image: guestlist]

Party-table
[image: party]

Guest-table
[image: guest]

Checkin-table
[image: checkin]

SQL skills is a bit rusty and I'd appreciate some pointers on how I should join this in a smarter way.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you'll provide sample data from the tables (check_in, guests etc) and the result of your query on the table (as in what you want to see). You didn't provide even the table structures

Comment: Sure, I'll revise my question with some more details.

Comment: @avi I've now added results and the domain of the related tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would try, assuming you have index on the relevant column.

Replacing

```
SELECT sum(guest.guest_count)
FROM guest
WHERE guest.party IN  -- Especially smelly
               (SELECT party.id
                FROM party
                WHERE party.guestlist = g.id
               )
```

By

```
SELECT sum(guest.guest_count) 
FROM guest g1
 JOIN party p on (party.id=g1.party)
WHERE p.guestlist=g.id
```

And changing this :

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT guestlist, count(*) parties
    FROM party
    GROUP BY guestlist
  ) p on p.guestlist = g.id
```

By

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT guestlist, count(guestlist) parties
    FROM party
    GROUP BY guestlist
) p on p.guestlist = g.id
```

I'm not saying that this will help you but it must. More info on lateral here https://blog.heapanalytics.com/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral/ it might help you since you both deals with event :-)

Comment: Wow thank you, that reference looks really promising. Must try this out tomorrow (posting from my nightstand).

Comment: Hmm, tried these changes but didn't seem to make any difference, the cost is identical and the time is about the same.

Comment: Don't have so much time right not, can you provide a SQLFiddle since you already provide a schema ? sorry, thanks